# atobin() and atohex() in systemverilog

Tags: system-verilog

Does anyone know about these 2 functions? Should the output of 'F'.atohex() be 0x16 or 0x46 (directly from the ASCII table)? I have googled this already, but some said the former one is correct while some said the other. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the result is 0xF. These functions do not have the greatest names. What both do is convert an ASCII string in a particular radix to an integral value. `atohex` assumes the string is formatted in hexadecimal.

Answer (score 3):

from LRM:

> — str.atoi() returns the integer corresponding to the ASCII decimal representation in str.
>
> — atohex interprets the string as hexadecimal.
>
> — atooct interprets the string as octal.
>
> — atobin interprets the string as binary.
>
> NOTE—These ASCII conversion functions return a 32-bit integer value

So, the result of the following:

```
string a = "F";
a.atohex();
```

ia a 32-bit integer: `32'hF`.

Comment: today I tried atobin()
when c="2" or "3"
the last 2 bits of c.atobin() gives all 0, but I want them to be 10 or 11, just the same as the binary representation of 2 and 3, am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: "2" or "3" are not representations of binary numbers. So, autobin did not work. You needed "10" or "11".

Comment: `atoi` converts decimal string, `atobin`,  converts binary string, `atohex` converts hex strings, ... `atoi("10") == atohex("A") == atobin("1010") == atooct("12")`